# How to decompose an isometry $f\in O(\mathbb{R}^3)$ into reflections?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a nondegenerate inner product space $(\mathbb{R}^3,\Phi)$.
 $O(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is the orthogonal group of  $\mathbb{R}^3$. How do you decompose an isometry $f\in O(\mathbb{R}^3)$ into reflections?

Comment: Generalize the procedure given in http://tur-www1.massey.ac.nz/~ctuffley/slides/threereflections.pdf to 3 dimensions.

Comment: giulio, please be sure to include your title question in the main body of the question too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We wish to decompose a given $f \in O(3)$ into reflections.

If $f$ fixes the point $(1,0,0)$, let $R_1$ be the identity.  Otherwise, let $R_1$ be a reflection that switches $(1,0,0)$ with $f(1,0,0)$.  In either case, the composition $g = R_1\circ f$ fixes the point $(1,0,0)$.

Note that $g$ is an orthogonal transformation, and therefore $g$ maps $(0,1,0)$ to some point on the $yz$-plane.  If $g$ fixes $(0,1,0)$, let $R_2$ be the identity.  Otherwise, let $R_2$ be a reflection that switches $(0,1,0)$ and $g(0,1,0)$.

Note that $R_2$ also fixes $(1,0,0)$, and therefore $R_3 = R_2\circ g$ fixes both $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$.  Thus $R_3$ is either the identity map or the reflection across the $xy$-plane.  Then
$$
f \;=\; R_1\circ R_2 \circ R_3
$$
is a decomposition of $f$ into at most three reflections.