# Decomposing isometries of $O(\mathbb{R}^3,\phi)$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is my problem:

Let be $\phi$ a nondegenerate inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$ represented by the symmetric matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Let be $f\in O(\mathbb{R}^3,\phi)$ so defined: $f(x):=Bx, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $B$ is:

$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{2}{3} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}-\frac{4}{3} 
\end{pmatrix}$$
I had to looking for three non-isotropic vectors: $v_1,v_2,v_3$ such that $f=\rho_{v_1}\circ\rho_{v_2}\circ\rho_{v_3}$ where (if $v_k$ is not isotrope) $\rho_{v_k}$ is a "parallel reflection" that is so defined:

$\rho_{v_k}(w):=-\lambda v_k + z$, $\forall w \in \mathbb{R}^3=Span(v_k)\bot Z_{v_k}$ where $w=\lambda v_k + z$ with $z\in Z_{v_k}:=Span(v_k)^{\bot}$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

I found an eigenvector (for $f$) $u_1=\begin{pmatrix} 
1\\
0\\
2 
\end{pmatrix}$
with eigenvalue $-1$. This is a non-isotropic vector and I suspect that it's a possible "$v_1$". Am I right?
Now I think I had to follow the algorithm exposed here: [How to decompose an isometry $f\in O(\mathbb{R}^3)$ into reflections?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637109/how-to-decompose-an-isometry-f-in-o-mathbbr3-into-reflections), but I don't know how I had to proceed and adapt it to my case. Please, can someone help me? I'm also happy to have some hints.

Comment: If it can be helpful I had calculate Span of $Z_{v_1}$: $Z_{v_1}=Span(\begin{pmatrix} 
2\\
0\\
1 
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 
0\\
1\\
0 
\end{pmatrix})$.